# What's C++ GUI Library support 32-bit character Unicode for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, unicode

My Windows application uses 32-bit characters (Unicode) for an Asian language. I don't know what C++ GUI library support it.

Edit: I used UTF-8 as (char *).

Comment: I tidied up a bit and noticed you tagged with utf-8, but your question talks about utf-32. Which are you using?

Comment: All GUI toolkits of note support Unicode.

Comment: Most GUI toolkits on Windows use the operating system default, utf-16.  You can convert from utf-8 to utf-16 with MultiByteToWideChar().  Or with mbrtowc() by setting the locale.  Or with a conversion function provided by the toolkit, they inevitably invent their own string type (CString, QString, wxString, System::String, HString etcetera).

Answer (score 2):

Is it actually using UTF-32? If so, you're going to need to convert them to UTF-8 or UTF-16, as needed by your GUI library. The conversion is generally easy, and most GUIs that have Unicode support will have some means of doing the conversion into their string format.

Comment: Data will be lost, because Chinese characters use > 2 bytes :-(

Comment: @dazzlingvit utf-8 and utf-16 are both variable-length encodings.

Comment: Characters use MORE than 2 bytes. I used UTF-8 as (char *)

Comment: @dazzlingvit: Yes, UTF-8 uses bytes. But each byte is *not a character*. Each byte is a [UTF-8 code unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Multiple code units are composed to form a [Unicode codepoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). That's *the entire point* of UTF-8: that you can encode all Unicode codepoints in a `char*`. [UTF-16 is the same way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16): if a codepoint can't fit in a 16-bit value, then it uses 2 16-bit values to encode it. Again, the whole point of UTF-16. Perhaps you should educate yourself on how the UTF's work.

Comment: @dazzling You don't know enough about Unicode encodings. I respectfully suggest you read about UTF-16 in particular. That is the native Windows encoding and it supports the full Unicode character set.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Unicode is supported in Qt, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt library supports unicode, as does windows forms, and probably a load of others. Qt has a lot of support for [internationalization](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html) as well.

Just as a side note, on Windows c++ wide characters are stored as utf-16, but as utf is variable width they can effectively store any character.